# application gateway back end pool and express route

Tags: azure

I just want to know if its possible to reference an internal expressroute onprem host for the back-end pool configuration of an application gateway.

The documentation is a bit vague on the subject.

Back-end server pool: The list of IP addresses of the back-end servers. The IP addresses listed should either belong to the virtual network subnet or should be a public IP/VIP. FQDN can also be used.

Thanks
Alex

Comment: hi, did you solve this?
I have a application gateway and it is not reaching an ip on-premise connected by a s2s-vpn. vm in the same vnet can reach it.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/application-gateway-introduction/), I believe it is possible to reference any IP address.

> The Application Gateway routes the HTTP traffic based on its
>   configuration whether it's a virtual machine, cloud service, web app,
>   or an **external IP address**.